# javascript regular expression to grab the state of 2 characters that is always following a city and a comma

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

Seems that google api for returns city and state from a zip code is just poorly made as they return a json object with `address_components` of which all have array list of elements with `long_name` and `short_name`

Now that would be fine , except that i cannot count on the state because in 3rd or the 4th array.  :/

The ONE thing that i do see in common is a **formatted_address** of which example is

```
formatted_address: "Lake Villa, IL 60046, USA"
```

Since that is the case then seems that a **regex** is what i want

**GOAL**

```
var city = "Lake Villa"
var state = "IL"
```

I don't want to replace....  here is some regex i was trying to work with

```
 var formatted_address = "Lake Villa, IL 60046, USA";
 alert(formatted_address.replace(/(.+)\-([A-Z]{2})$/, "$1, $2").replace("\-", " "));
```

Comment: Your formatted_address has no `-`, why do you use it in the pattern? What are the requirements / rules? And try `var m = formatted_address.match(/^([^,]+), ([A-Z]{2})/)` -> `m[1]` and `m[2]`

Comment: trying this   var city = formatted_address.replace(/^(.+?)/,);

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/3ot55Lkm/2

Comment: GOAL  is what i want  out of the formatted_address

Comment: YES,  sweet    i forked it    https://jsfiddle.net/a0hc4hp7/     COULD @WiktorStribiżew  you create an answer so i can credit you    thx for the help

Comment: That regex will always work even if it is no space in city and more trailing commas etc..   right ?

Comment: `/^([^,]+),\s*([A-Z]{2})\b/` will work even if there are no whitespaces, see the explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capture 1 or more chars other than `,` from the start into one group and then match a comma with whitespaces and then capture 2 ASCII letters as a whole word:

```js
var formatted_address = "Lake Villa, IL 60046, USA";
var res = formatted_address.match(/^([^,]+),\s*([A-Z]{2})\b/);
if (res) {
  console.log(res[1]);
  console.log(res[2]);
}
```

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^,]+)` - Group 1 (city): 1 or more chars other than `,`
- `,` - a comma
- `\s*` -  0+ whitespaces
- `([A-Z]{2})`  - 2 uppercase ASCII letters
- `\b` - a word boundary, the 2 letters must be followed with a non-word char or end of string.

Comment: Why should I use this vs. the other answers?  I do like it.. its clean and you explain very well..   Just looking for any confirmation as to opinion vs. others

Answer (score 2):

Why not try splitting on commas, and just getting the values from the resulting array?

```
let city, state;

let input = "Lake Villa, IL 60046, USA";

input = input.split(",");

city = input[0];

state = input[1].replace(/[0-9]/g, '').trim(); // removes the numbers, and excess whitespace

console.log(city,state);
```

This results in:

```
state = IL
city = Lake Villa
```

[Codepen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QgXooJ?editors=0012)

Comment: While I suppose this is easier for someone like me with a lack of regex,  seems like other answer is possibly cleaner or do you see problems with his answer?

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

```js
var str = "Lake Villa, IL 60046, USA";
var matches = str.match(/(.+?), (..)/);

var city = matches[1];
var state = matches[2];

console.log(city, state); // -> Lake Villa IL
```

Or in ES6:

```js
const str = "Lake Villa, IL 60046, USA";
const [_, city, state] = str.match(/(.+?), (..)/);

console.log(city, state); // -> Lake Villa IL
```

Comment: Can you explain you this is a better answer than the others?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's better, it's just different. I think the shorter regex is easier to manage/debug. In that way it's better. The others are more explicit with more of the logic spelled out so maybe you might find that better. Just pick the one you like best.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend searching first at [Txt2RE.com](http://txt2re.com). It had an interesting regex for that:

```
<script language=javascript>
  var txt='Lake Vila, IL 60046, USA';

  var re1='(.*?),'; // Command Seperated Values 1
  var re2='(,)';    // Any Single Character 1
  var re3='(\\s+)'; // White Space 1
  var re4='((?:(?:AL)|(?:AK)|(?:AS)|(?:AZ)|(?:AR)|(?:CA)|(?:CO)|(?:CT)|(?:DE)|(?:DC)|(?:FM)|(?:FL)|(?:GA)|(?:GU)|(?:HI)|(?:ID)|(?:IL)|(?:IN)|(?:IA)|(?:KS)|(?:KY)|(?:LA)|(?:ME)|(?:MH)|(?:MD)|(?:MA)|(?:MI)|(?:MN)|(?:MS)|(?:MO)|(?:MT)|(?:NE)|(?:NV)|(?:NH)|(?:NJ)|(?:NM)|(?:NY)|(?:NC)|(?:ND)|(?:MP)|(?:OH)|(?:OK)|(?:OR)|(?:PW)|(?:PA)|(?:PR)|(?:RI)|(?:SC)|(?:SD)|(?:TN)|(?:TX)|(?:UT)|(?:VT)|(?:VI)|(?:VA)|(?:WA)|(?:WV)|(?:WI)|(?:WY)))(?![a-z])';    // US State 1
  var re5='(\\s+)'; // White Space 2
  var re6='(\\d+)'; // Integer Number 1
  var re7='(,)';    // Any Single Character 2
  var re8='(\\s+)'; // White Space 3
  var re9='(USA)';  // Word 1

  var p = new RegExp(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9,["i"]);
  var m = p.exec(txt);
  if (m != null)
  {
      var usstate1=m[4];
  }
</script>
```